# Python tkinter error:'Variable is not defined" even though it is define

Tags: python

When I run this code is says "UserName is not defined even" though its defined in the function right below it. Do the functions have to be a certain order and if so is there a way to fix that.

```
from tkinter import *

def MasterLogin():
    Name = UserName.get()
    Email = RegisterEmail.get()
    Password = RegisterPassword.get()
    MasterLogin = Tk()
    MasterLogin.title('Login')
    MasterLogin.geometry('260x100')
    LoginEmail = Entry(MasterLogin, width=30).grid(row=0, column=1)
    LoginEmailText = Label(MasterLogin, text=Email).grid(row=0, column=0)

def MasterRegister():
    MasterRegister = Tk()
    MasterRegister.title('Register')
    MasterRegister.geometry('260x100')
    UserName = Entry(MasterRegister, width=30).grid(row=0, column=1)
    UserNameText = Label(MasterRegister, text='Name ').grid(row=0, column=0)
    RegisterEmail = Entry(MasterRegister, width=30).grid(row=1, column=1)
    RegisterEmailText = Label(MasterRegister, text='Email ').grid(row=1, column=0)
    RegisterPassword = Entry(MasterRegister, width=30).grid(row=2, column=1)
    RegisterPasswordText = Label(MasterRegister, text='Password ').grid(row=2, column=0)
    RegisterCont = Button(MasterRegister, text='Continue', width=25, bg='blue', fg='white', 
                                                 command=MasterLogin).grid(row=3, column=1)
```

Comment: is this all your code? you are not calling your functions here so it won't output anything but I bet that you are trying to access a local variable in the global scope

Comment: You need to read up on the concept of *local variables*.  Absolutely nothing in `MasterRegister()` is accessible outside of that function.

Comment: `UserName` is *local* to `MasterRegister` and *not* defined in `MasterLogin`.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at this code I would suggest the following. Create a class that handles windows. In this, you can easily have functions that do what you need to do, in this code it seems you are using functions as the end all be all for your code, this would be inefficient for your code and not very future proof.

Without a class you can still achieve what you want for an Entry box, the issues here with your example is that your variables are declared along a private scope making them inaccessible to the rest of the program, this can be fixed with declaring global within a certain area of your code but this can become messy and render functions almost useless for private functionality (this can lead to many errors)

Heres my simple example for an entry box with a button that gets the data in it

```
from tkinter import *


def ButtonPress(entry):
  
  entry = entry
  print(entry.get())
  return entry.get()


F = Tk()

F.geometry("300x100")
F.config(bg="black")

myEntry = Entry()
myEntry.pack()

myButton = Button(text="Enter",command=lambda : ButtonPress(myEntry))
myButton.pack()


F.mainloop()
```